# Does this URL exist? RCurl says no

Tags: html, xml, r, web-scraping, rcurl

The URL of interest is:

```
http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.htm&r=10&f=G&l=50&d=PTXT&OS=AN/(nortel)&RS=AN/nortel&Query=AN/(nortel)&Srch1=nortel.ASNM.&NextList1=Next 50 Hits
```

The chosen function to test its existence is:

```
> url.exists("http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.htm&r=10&f=G&l=50&d=PTXT&OS=AN/(nortel)&RS=AN/nortel&Query=AN/(nortel)&Srch1=nortel.ASNM.&NextList1=Next 50 Hits")
[1] FALSE
```

Why dis no work?  The URL clearly exists and resolves in chrome and using `htmlTreeParse` on the URL works just fine.

Comment: it is invalid, so my guess would be that at the very least the spaces need to be escaped either as `+` or as `%20`, maybe you'll need to escape the parentheses as well, don't know for sure. Browsers are generally very lenient and do this for you

Comment: Why would htmlTreeParse work on it?

Comment: Don't know, it would have to do the proper escaping internally for it to work, it cannot be used as it is in an HTTP-request (a space separates the URL from the HTTP/1.1 version string), either way it's malformed according to the URL RFC

Comment: Interesting.  I'm assuming in the querystring the slashes would need to be changed to %2F?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure they're fine, slashes are valid, it doesn't matter where they are. But I'm a bit rusty on my RFCs so you might want to double check. :)

Comment: Escaping the spaces only will make the URL work, but `url.exists` still seems to report FALSE.

Comment: Escaping the spaces yields a "200 Script results follows" response along with the html-page, perhaps it's looking for a "200 Ok" status, and is overzealous in parsing it, overlooking the fact that it's a 200 code?

Comment: Also, it's not responding properly to HEAD requests, which `url.exists` is probably using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess would be that `url.exists` is using a HTTP HEAD-request, which the server seems unable to handle:

```
$ telnet patft.uspto.gov 80
Trying 151.207.240.26...
Connected to patft.uspto.gov.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD /netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.htm&r=10&f=G&l=50&d=PTXT&OS=AN/(nortel)&RS=AN/nortel&Query=AN/(nortel)&Srch1=nortel.ASNM.&NextList1=Next+50+Hits HTTP/1.1
Host: patft.uspto.gov
Connection: close

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

So server broken, not RCurl.